# Make one-liner if statement more fancy

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement

My code is as below:

```
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
$command1;
$command2;
$command3;
fi
```

Can I have a one liner to do the same? I have this but looking for something better and fancy.

```
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then $command1;$command2;$command3; fi
```

Comment: How can you improve your one line?

Comment: Why should it be 'fancy'?

Answer (score 1):

Your attempted oneliner works just fine, as in this example:

```
commnd1='echo foo'
commnd2='echo bar'
commnd3='echo baz'
true
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then $commnd1;$commnd2;$commnd3;fi
```

You can also use `&&` and command grouping:

```
[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && { cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; }
```

Comment: You don't need to test `$?`: `previous_command && { cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; }`